# If else seems to be ignored in my java application

Tags: java

I just started programming in java and i am creating a simple waiting list.
it al seems to work well but i decided to include a if else construction to check the textfield not beeing empty. the problem is that it seems to be ignored because i don't get a error or something.. and i googled alot for the if else example and i can't solve the problem somehow.. what am i doing wrong? below you can find the relevant code. Thanks in advance.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // check if veld1 is filled in.
    if ( veld1 == null || veld1.equals( "" ) ) { 
        // give error
        System.out.println("U heeft niets ingevuld in veld1");
    }
    else {
        veld4.setText( veld3.getText() );
        veld3.setText( veld2.getText() );
        veld2.setText( veld1.getText() );
        textveld1.append( veld4.getText() + "\n" );
        veld1.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems veld1 is not a string, but some Swing control.
You probably want to do

```
if(veld1.getText() == null || veld1.getText().equals( "" )
```

Comment: Ah that does the trick! thanks alot. only your komma must be a dot.. ;) is it also possible to print this error on the screen instead of the eclipse console? ( sorry if its a silly question i just started java so i don;t know a lot used to script in PHP and program in C# a little bit )

Comment: I'd be surprised if `veld1.getText()` would return `null` if `veld1` is some Swing component. But making certain doesn't harm.

Comment: hmm so veld1.getText().trim().quals("") should be enough right cuz it never will return null?

Answer (score 1):

If the `veld1` holds a JTextField, you probably want to change the statement to `veld1 == null || veld1.getText() == null || veld1.getText().equals( "" )`, as in your current code you check if the field itself exists, not its content.

Comment: no i want to check the content. so i don't think its necessary for now to check for that but i'll keep that in mind!

Comment: i updated the answer slightly to clarify, my point is the same as nos's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to grant without seeing the rest of it, but `veld1.equals("")` looks suspicious. You are comparing `veld1` to the empty String, but `veld1` looks like a component. Maybe you meant `veld1.getText().equals("")` (and, similarly, `veld1.getText() == null`)

Answer (score 0):

veld1.equals("") is not the same as veld1.getText().equals(""), the first one is comparing the veld1 object to an empty string, and will always be false.